# Saving action sheet Values/User Defaults

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, uiactionsheet

So in my app I'm using a Action sheet which displays which animations to use. Everything is implemented, however, I'm having trouble using user defaults to save the selected row and then pass that along to the rest of my code. I've used user defaults before on `UISwitch`, but this is different I suppose.

The portion I'm using is a `UITableView`. in the `didselectrow`:

```
                //Animation Picker
                [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

                NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"Choose your style.";

                BlockActionSheet *sheet = [BlockActionSheet sheetWithTitle:actionSheetTitle];

                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


                [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Zoom Out" block:^{
                    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation Style: Zoom Out"]];
                    //User Defaults
                    [prefs setObject:@"Zoom Out" forKey:@"Zoom"];

                    cellTitle = @"Zoom Out";
                }];

                [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Drop In" block:^{
                    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation Style: Drop In"]];
                    //User Defaults
                    [prefs setObject:@"Drop In" forKey:@"Drop"];

                    cellTitle = @"Drop In";
                }];

                [sheet setDestructiveButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel" block:nil];
                [sheet showInView:self.view];

                [prefs synchronize];
                [tableView reloadData];
```

Which should send the info to use the proper `animationController`:

```
-(void)infoButtonAction:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    if ([userDefaults stringForKey:@"Zoom"]) {

        AppInfoViewController * info = [[AppInfoViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *vc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:info];
        self.animationController = [[ZoomAnimationController alloc] init];
        vc.transitioningDelegate  = self;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        [info release];
    }

    else if ([userDefaults stringForKey:@"Drop"]) {

        AppInfoViewController * info = [[AppInfoViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *vc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:info];
        self.animationController = [[DropAnimationController alloc] init];
        vc.transitioningDelegate  = self;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        [info release];
    }

    NSLog(@"App Info");
}
```

Also should update the cell displaying which `animationController` was selected:

```
                NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [prefs synchronize];
                [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation Style:"]];

                if ([prefs stringForKey:@"Zoom"]){
                    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation Style: Zoom Out"]];
                }

                else if ([prefs stringForKey:@"Drop"]) {
                    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation Style: Drop In"]];
                }

                UIView *animation = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
                animation.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.176 green:0.176 blue:0.176 alpha:1];
                cell.backgroundView = animation;
```

However, nothing is getting saved. What am I missing?

Thank you for any help.

UPDATE: 1/3
I managed to get everything working with the updated code above. The only thing now is it won't save the style I choose. If I choose Drop In, and re open the table, it reverts back to Zoom Out. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is any if or else working ? Please NSLog the NSUserDefaults value

Comment: Got side tracked. I ended up taking another method. OP has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Take one String object that

```
    NSString *OneString = [NSString stringWithFormat: selectedValue];
```

and Use that OneString in if condition and rest of the code.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but when I select another value, it doesnt save it, the table reload pushes it back to the other one.